# why generating function $A(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ can be denoted as $\frac{1}{1-z}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

It is easy to see that $1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ is equal to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ when $1 > z > 0$ and for $z >= 1$, they are not equivalent. So I have thought $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is just a short for the more complex formula $1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ and it has nothing to do with the value of the function. But later when I look at some materials about generating function (e.g. analytic combinatorics), I find that people also do some algebra operations on the generating function. For example, for the problem of how many trees are there with $N$ nodes, the generating function is $G(z) = z(1 + G(z) + G(z)^2 + \cdots)$ and thus $G(z)=\frac{z}{1-G(z)}$. I regard $\frac{1}{1-G(z)}$ is just a short of $1 + G(z) + G(z)^2 + \cdots$ here and all things look good. To get the closed form of $G(z)$, however, they transform $G(z)=\frac{z}{1-G(z)}$ to $G(z)-G(z)^2=z$, which is an algebra operation. We know that $1 + G(z) + G(z)^2 + \cdots$ and $\frac{1}{1-G(z)}$ are not necessarily the same. So is the solution after we solving $G(z)-G(z)^2=z$ exactly the $G(z)$ we expect?

Comment: The basics of the needed theory are nicely developed here: Ivan Niven, "Formal Power Series", *Am. Math. Monthly* **76** (1969), 871–889, [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317940).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with *formal* power series with, say, real coefficients; actually the coefficients could be in any commutative ring, let's assume for simplicity it's a field or, if you prefer, the real numbers.

The formal power series form a ring which contains the ring of polynomials in one variable as a subring. Addition is defined componentwise, while multiplication is defined with the convolution (or Cauchy product):
$$
\biggl(\,\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n\biggr)\biggl(\,\sum_{n\ge0}b_nz^n\biggr)=\sum_{n\ge0}c_nz^n
$$
where
$$
c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}\qquad(n\ge 0)
$$
One can check that all ring axioms are satisfied. Now, considering $1-z$ as the formal power series in which all coefficients of $z^n$ are zero from $2$ onwards,
$$
(1-z)\sum_{n\ge0}z^n=
\sum_{n\ge0}z^n-\sum_{n\ge1}z^n=1
$$
so $1-z$ is the inverse of $\sum_{n\ge0}z^n$ in the ring of formal power series, which justifies writing
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$

Convergence is not taken into consideration.

The reasoning with
$$
G(z)=z(1+G(z)+G(z)^2+\dotsb)
$$
can be justified by considering rings of formal power series with coefficients in the ring of formal power series. A bit complicated, but not so difficult either.

Answer (score 2):

Generating functions are *formal* power series, which essentially means that we are not concerned with analytic issues of convergence.  (The symbol $z$ is not meant to stand for a complex number, or any other type of number, for that matter.)

Formal power series *do* support most of the algebraic operations that you are familiar with, including manipulating closed form "short-hand" such as
$$
1 + z + z^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - z}. 
$$

Comment: so generating functions are just power series rather than "function"s, right? $1 + z + z^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-z}$ just means that the power series $1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ is the quotient of the power series $1$ and the power series $1-z$.